# Deleting a node from RST tree using double pointers

Tags: c

I've got a RST tree which structure is:

```
struct node
{
    int key;
    node *left, *right;
} *root;
```

My function which aim is to delete a node with 'v' key:

```
void Delete (int v)
{
    node** p = Search(v);
    node** tmp = p;
    if (!(*p)) return;
    if((*p)->left==null && (*p)->right==NULL)
    {
        p = null;
        return;
    }
    while((*tmp)->left != null || (*tmp)->right != NULL)
    {
        if ((*tmp)->left != NULL)
            tmp = &((*tmp)->left);
        else
            tmp = &((*tmp)->right);
    }
    (*tmp)->right = (*p)->right;
    (*tmp)->left = (*p)->left;
    p = tmp;
    tmp = null;
}
```

Generally I am not sure when I should write 'tmp' and '*tmp'. Can you explain me my mistakes here?

Answer (score 0):

```
(!tmp)->right == NULL

node** temp = p;

temp->right, temp alone is a pointer to a node pointer. It has no right.
(*temp)->right.
```

Comment: Yes, that was a spelling mistake. It should be: (*tmp)->right != NULL

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.